# List Index Out of Range Error in this Fibonacci code

Tags: python

If I run this code

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    if n == 2:
        return [1, 1]
    else:
        return fib(n - 1).append(fib(n - 1)[n - 1] + fib(n - 2)[n - 2])


print fib(3)
```

I get an error, List Index Out of Range.

Comment: `return fib( ... ).append( ... )` will return `None` even if `fib( ... )` is a valid list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append in a `return`. Additionally, you made an off by 1 error in the `append` statement which caused the index out of range error. If you store the previous answer in a list, which I called `fiblist`, you can then append to that list and then return it.

This code produces the answer you want:

```
def fib(n):
        if n == 1:
            return [1]
        if n == 2:
            return [1, 1]
        else:
          fiblist = (fib(n - 1))
          fiblist.append(fib(n - 1)[n - 2] + fib(n - 2)[n - 3])
          return fiblist

print(fib(3))
```